# Wordpress hiding Post Div

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wanted to know how to make it possible that if there is no post i would like to be able to hide the DIV that controls the latest blog post only having them appear when someone post somethign on a blog..

Somewhat like a position in joomla but in this case i am using wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on ceejyaoz's answer

```
if(have_posts())
{
    //... do HTML in here 
}
```

If there aren't posts, the HTML, and probably the `div` you are talking about, won't show up. You can even use an else statement for a custom message if there are no posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `have_posts()` function to detect whether there are any posts in the loop, and do conditionals based on that.